Does ubuntu supports new processors like intel core ultra and arc graphic card
I brought a new Lenovo laptop Ideapad pro 5i, with intel core ultra 7. I am fed up with all the Microsoft nonsense lately and wanted to shift to Linux. One of my friend suggested Ubuntu to start with, but i am concerned that will it work with these new processors. Also this laptop has a copilot button can i remap that button in ubuntu to do something else like open terminal or something. are intel arc graphics supported, and is there a way to get lenovo vantage to get updated bios

Just be sure to use latest version, currently 24.04.1LTS for the tests.

so , if i use the latest version than it will be fine?

I know there are some issues with Linux running on the latest Lunar Lake processors (Intel® Core™ Ultra 7 processor 258V Series 2), how is your experience so far, everything (wifi, bluetooth, suspend, power management, etc.) works? Thanks
